# Google Map API credentials requiring multiple rows for each domain

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-api, privileges

I'm trying to add credentials for additional URLs to use my Google Maps API, but when I do, unless I add all three rows:

```
www.domain.com
www.domain.com*
www.domain.com/*
```

I'll [sometimes] get a warning that the domain doesn't have privileges.

Am I doing something wrong, or do I really need to have three rows per domain? Seems kind of silly.

I'm adding the credentials here:

```
https://console.developers.google.com/project/xxxxxxxxx/apiui/credential
```

Comment: Which client ID are you using and for what API?